# Flex button skins return to default

Tags: apache-flex, button, components, skin, states

I have a problem which involves skinned buttons returning to their default skins after certain actions occur in my application. Below I have included a partial screenshot where you can observe the problem.

[image]

The left button is returned to its default skin after it was clicked (the click triggers a state transition). The right button is the default skinned button. Note that my mouse is neither over nor pressing the left button.

The code for the Button Skin is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<fx:Metadata>
    <![CDATA[ 
        [HostComponent("spark.components.Button")]
    ]]>
</fx:Metadata>

<fx:Script fb:purpose="styling">
    <![CDATA[         
        import spark.components.Group;

        static private const exclusions:Array = ["labelDisplay"];

        override public function get colorizeExclusions():Array {return exclusions;}

        override protected function initializationComplete():void
        {
            useChromeColor = true;
            super.initializationComplete();
        }            
    ]]>        
</fx:Script>

<s:states>
    <s:State name="up" />
    <s:State name="over" />
    <s:State name="down" />
    <s:State name="disabled" />
</s:states>

<s:Rect id="fill" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" radiusX="2">
    <s:fill>
        <s:LinearGradient rotation="270">
            <s:GradientEntry color.down="#545454"
                             color.over="#444444"
                             color="#343434"
                             alpha="0.95"/>
            <s:GradientEntry color.down="#767676"
                             color.over="#666666"
                             color="#565656"
                             alpha="0.95"/>
        </s:LinearGradient>
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>

<s:Rect id="border" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" width="69" height="20" radiusX="3">
    <s:stroke>
        <s:SolidColorStroke id="borderStroke" weight="1" color="#343434" caps="round" joints="round" />
    </s:stroke>
</s:Rect>

<s:Label id="labelDisplay"
         textAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle" maxDisplayedLines="1" fontSize="12"
         left="10" right="10" verticalCenter="0"
         color="#FFFFFF" fontFamily="SegoeUI">
</s:Label>
```

Here's the code for the transition that is causing the problem:

```
        <s:Transition fromState="State0" toState="State1">
        <s:Sequence targets="{[contacts_nocontacts, contacts_list, button_contacts, button_add, button_delete, ac_vgroup]}">
            <s:Parallel>
                <s:Fade target="{contacts_nocontacts}" alphaFrom="1" alphaTo="0" duration="200" />
                <s:Fade target="{contacts_list}" alphaFrom="1" alphaTo="0" duration="200" />
                <s:Fade target="{button_add}" alphaFrom="1" alphaTo="0" duration="200" />
                <s:Fade target="{button_delete}" alphaFrom="1" alphaTo="0" duration="200" />
            </s:Parallel>
            <s:RemoveAction targets="{[contacts_nocontacts, contacts_list, button_add, button_delete]}" />
            <s:AddAction targets="{[button_contacts, ac_vgroup]}" />
            <s:Parallel>
                <s:Fade target="{button_contacts}" alphaFrom="0" alphaTo="1" duration="300" />
                <s:Fade target="{ac_vgroup}" alphaFrom="0" alphaTo="1" duration="300" />
            </s:Parallel>
        </s:Sequence>
    </s:Transition>
```

Comment: Ctrl+H `setStyle("skinClass"` maybe?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say, please rephrase.

Comment: I'm unclear on the problem.  Are you trying to return the button to it's default skin class; or do you want to prevent it from happening?  How are you creating the buttons?  How are you setting the skins?  What is the code behind your custom skin?  What sort of transitions are you using?

Comment: I am trying to prevent it from happening. The buttons are created using MXML and the skin is globally applied through CSS. I have added the skin code to the question. The transitions are simple MXML Spark Fade transitions on the container of the buttons. The button above (left) is used to trigger the transition.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that skin (although I can't see why you're setting 'useChromeColor' to 'true' if you're not using it anywhere), so the error must be elsewhere. Something must be reassigning the skinclass of that button.

Comment: That's what I thought but skins are only assigned through css, and all skins are globally assigned...

Comment: @Chris Smith, the something is overriding it then.  Is there more than one CSS? How is it being loaded? etc etc

Comment: @J_A_X there is only one CSS file which is loaded through an `fx:Style` tag right after the `s:Application` tag.

Comment: Help us out here.  There's something that's happening that's changing the stylesheet.  We can't just pick possible solutions out of a hat...

Comment: By the process of elimination I've discovered that the code for one transition was causing this effect on the button. I've added the transition code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the skin is being set to the spark.skins.spark.DefaultButtonSkin (not to be confused with the normal Button skin - spark.skins.spark.ButtonSkin).  This happens when you set emphasized="true" on the Button or that button is being used as a default Button in a Form.

See this thread for an example of how to customize the emphasized skin: http://forums.adobe.com/message/3811868

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Skin is reset when focus is lost on a button that is set as `Default button`. It's standard behaviour, a quick fix can be found beneath (it's the same solution as the one Steven pointed out, but It's easier to have it on this actual page)

```
s|Button.emphasized {
    skinClass: ClassReference("MyNewButtonSkin");
}
```

Just attach the same button skinClass on the `emphasized` style property of your button. The best way to do this the quickest is to do it with above CSS. On this way you can target all the buttons at once!